# BluetoothDevice BroadcastReceiver onReceived() not called

Tags: bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, acl

I have service with BroadcastReceiver.
Register actions:

- BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED
- BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED
- BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED

After connect/disconnect with other device on the Galaxy S3 and Fly iq280 onReceived() was called, but on a Google Nexus 7 is not.

Maybe I do something wrong?

My code:

```
private void registerConnectionBroadcast() {
    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    IntentFilter filter4 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter3);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter4);
}

private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        String deviceAddress = device != null ? device.getAddress() : "";
        Log.d(TAG, deviceAddress);
        if (!isConnected()) {
            SettingsSupport.setDeviceAddress(deviceAddress, ReceiverService.this);
        }

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            Log.d("ConnectionBroadcastReceiver", "Device found");//Device found
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d("ConnectionBroadcastReceiver", "Device is now connected");//Device is now connected
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d("ConnectionBroadcastReceiver", "Done searching");//Done searching
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d("ConnectionBroadcastReceiver", "Device is about to disconnect");//Device is about to disconnect
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d("ConnectionBroadcastReceiver", "Device has disconnected");//Device has disconnected
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth state is changed to " + state);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was called on Nexus 4 but wasn't on Samsung S3.
I don't think that it would make any difference, but you can try registering the receiver in the manifest xml.